# is sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier stuck at predicting most frequent category?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree

Below is the details of my code that I think is relevant to my question.

1. I created the target binary variable PP like this, with PP's distribution attached. As you see, `False/0` ~66% and `True/1` =34%

```
pandas_df['PP'] =(pandas_df['DET'].fillna(0) <1).astype('str')  

False    48114
True     25089
Name: FP, dtype: int64
```

2. Below is the model code. The goal is predict the probability of TRUE, as most models do

```
X= pandas_df[predictors]
y2= pandas_df.PP
tree_clf =DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=3, random_state=42,min_samples_leaf=500)
tree_clf.fit(X, y2)
```

3. Then I visualize the model as below (I left blank feature_names intentionally since it is long)

```
 dot_data2 =tree.export_graphviz(tree_clf,out_file=None,feature_names=(),....                                           

 pydot_graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data2)
 pydot_graph.set_size('"0.5,0.5!"')
 pydot_graph.write_png('resized_tree.png')
 DTgraph=graphviz.Source(dot_data2)
 DTgraph
```

The code is error free. Graph appears meaningful.

BUT: in each leaf/node displayed, it says `Class=False`. I ran a test by creating another variable PP2 to just flip PP 0 to 1 and 1 to 0. It then says Class=True because in PP2 it is True that is 66%.

I can live with PP2, twist my head a bit to understand it right. But nightmare to present the tree to business audience. I read through sklearn documentation and user guide. Did not find ways to force it to predict probability of TRUE. Am I misreading Class=False?

Comment: please post a link to the tree plot, as well as the accuracy of your model after training

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately the work is company work and link is not doable. I add verbally details of the trees in the Answer Your Question Section below if that is OK. Thanks.

Comment: Please do **not** use the answer space for adding info - edit & update your question instead.